# How to treat NULL values as 0 from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables joined by `user_id`.  In the query below I'm comparing `act_val` in table_two to make sure it's in between or equal to `min_val` and `max_val` from table_one.  But sometimes a `user_id` in table_one isn't found in table_two.  In those cases, I want the `act_val` to be treated as if it were 0 and qualify where table_one's `min_val` is lower.  Is that possible?  How so?

```
SELECT tb1.id FROM table_one tb1 
INNER JOIN table_two tb2 WHERE 
   tb1.min_val <= tb2.act_val AND tb1.min_val >= tb2.act_val 
   AND tb2.user_id = tb1.user_id 
GROUP BY ad.id;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the user_id link in the LEFT JOIN condition (ON clause), and the rest in the WHERE clause (filter).  tb2.act_val is treated as 0 when it is missing, using [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).  I also fixed up your 2nd condition, it should be     tb1.**max**_val >=     not     tb1.**min**_val >=

```
     SELECT tb1.id
        FROM table_one tb1 
   LEFT JOIN table_two tb2 ON tb2.user_id = tb1.user_id
       WHERE tb1.min_val <= IFNULL(tb2.act_val,0)
         AND tb1.max_val >= IFNULL(tb2.act_val,0)
    GROUP BY tb1.id;
```

[LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table. You can use this fact to find rows in a table that have no counterpart in another table:

Comment: I implemented this but the left join made my queries take minutes to calculate (100x slower).  I have other inner joins and conditions in there.  Is this normal?  Can I mix LEFT JOINs and INNER JOINs?

Comment: You can mix inner/left joins, but you MUST ensure that it is done in the right order. Not only that, LEFT JOINs means you want all records from the left even if there are no records to match on the right - by definition this increases the number of records to process for the rest of your query

Answer (score 1):

Use an OUTER join (LEFT in the following example) to get the all the TABLE1 records that may or may not have a matching user_id value in TABLE2.  Then construct the WHERE clause to filter down the record set to what you want:

```
   SELECT tb1.id
     FROM table_one tb1 
LEFT JOIN table_two tb2 ON tb2.user_id = tb1.user_id 
    WHERE tb2.act_val BETWEEN tb1.min_val AND tb1.max_val
       OR tb1.min_val < 0
 GROUP BY tb1.id
```

Comment: Almost the same as what I was about to post, only in my case it would have been something like `...ON tb2.user_id = tb1.user_id AND tb2.act_val BETWEEN tb1.min_val AND tb1.max_val WHERE tb2.user_id IS NULL OR tb1.min_val < 0`. Yours is a nice little trick to make it more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IS_NULL or IS_NOT_NULL operators. Please see
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFNULL(tbl2.act_val, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `inner join` to `left join`
2. Use `coalesce(tb2.act_val, 0)` instead of `tb2.act_val`

PS Also - your query looks incorrect because you refers to undefined table ad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
WHERE COALESCE(tb1.min_val, 0) <= tb2.act_val COALESCE(tb1.min_val, 0) >= tb2.act_val
```